Anyons in the Ising model
My understanding of conformal field theory is that it can be used to examine the critical point of a given classical / quantum field theory, since you can easily get the critical parameters. In the CFT, you have some primary fields with accompanying fusion rules. But, what do the fusion rules mean in the original theory?
To be concrete, it can be shown that the 2D Ising model is equivalent to the free electron gas CFT. This CFT is equivalent to the M(4,3) minimal model which has 3 primary fields which have some fusion and braiding rules. My question is if there are really exotic excitations at criticality in this simple spin model. What do they look like?
